# How can I fix the formatting issue with the separating line in modelsummary output tables?

Tags: r, regression, modelsummary, knitr-spin

When I summarize my regression outputs in a modelsummary table, I get an unpleasant formatting problem.

I used the following code:

```
modelsummary(ols, statistic = "p.value")
```

and get the following output when I knit it to PDF.

[Output after knitting to PDF](https://i.stack.imgur.com/2OTuz.png)

The separating line has these colons and is not nicely formatted.

Does anyone know a way to fix this issue. Many thanks.

Comment: Welcome to SO! Could you provide [a minimal reproducible example](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/5963269/how-to-make-a-great-r-reproducible-example) of your issue, i.e. a minimal working Rmd file? For example running `ols <- lm(mpg ~ hp, data = mtcars)` and your provided code in an otherwise empty Rmd worked fine for me and the rendered pdf shows no colons. I'm using `modelsummary` version `1.4.1`.

Comment: Also you may want to check the section header and see if `results = 'asis'` is specified (see https://bookdown.org/yihui/rmarkdown-cookbook/results-asis.html)

Comment: Felix, can you make sure you have installed the `kableExtra` package? It looks like tables are printed as markdown instead of LaTeX, and that can happen when kableExtra is not available on the local computer. (I am the modelsummary maintainer.)

Comment: Unfortunately, non of your suggestions was successful. I installed kableExtra,  MacTex, and tinytex. Many thanks for your help.